# boost::thread_group hangs forever after threads complete

Tags: c++, boost

I have a simple program that computes the lemoine of n (and minimizes p), for all n in a range. I'm trying to use boost::thread_group to farm out jobs using a specified number of cores. Here is my code:

```
int is_prime(unsigned int number)
{
        if (number <= 1) return 0;
        unsigned int i;
        for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {
                if (number % i == 0) return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}

void lemoine(unsigned int n)
{
        unsigned int q, p;
        for (q = n/2; q > 0; q--) {
                p = n - 2 * q;
                if (is_prime(p) && is_prime(q)) {
                        printf("%d = %d + 2*%d\n", n, p, q);
                        return;
                }
        }
}


void guess(unsigned int lower, unsigned int upper, unsigned int cores)
{
        unsigned int n;
        boost::asio::io_service svc;
        boost::asio::io_service::work work(svc);
        boost::thread_group threadpool;

        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &svc));
        }

        for (n = lower; n <= upper; n+=2) {
                svc.post(std::bind(lemoine, n));
        }

        threadpool.join_all();
}
```

I've cobbled this together from various examples found online. The problem is threadpool.join_all() never returns. I can see from the printed output that all my jobs completed, but still it hangs. One example I found suggests issuing a svc.stop() before the join, but this makes the output unpredictable, since it clearly kills the jobs before they've completed (rather than waiting for them to complete).
How do I ensure all the jobs complete, and bail when they have?

Comment: http://thisthread.blogspot.com/2011/04/multithreading-with-asio.html is an example I was looking at, as well as the correction mentioned in the comments. Neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes hangs on the call of `io_service::run` because you created `io_service::work` object ([work reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__work/work/overload1.html)). `io_service::run` can return only if destructor of `work` is called - what is impossible in your case, because dtor of work is called after `join_all` (when function goes out of scope). You can resolve this issue by creating `work` instance on heap (then you can manually delete this object, what call dtor of `work` and `io_service::run` can return):

```
void guess(unsigned int lower, unsigned int upper, unsigned int cores)
{
        unsigned int n;
        boost::asio::io_service svc;
        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work =     // ADDED
           std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(svc); // ADDED
        boost::thread_group threadpool;

        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &svc));
        }

        for (n = lower; n <= upper; n+=2) {
                svc.post(std::bind(lemoine, n));
        }

        work.reset(); // delete work, ADDED
        threadpool.join_all();
}
```

After deleting `work` by `work.reset()` your threads end when theirs job are done.